# How to change the encoding format of existed file?

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a lot of files which encoded in `UTF-8` , and I want to change `UTF-8` to `ANSI` format . I know I can use the program `notepad` in windows to resave the file to `ANSI` format , but there are too many files.

So how do I change that by powershell ? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Get-Content` to read in a file's contents into a variable:

```
$contents = Get-Content foo.txt
```

Then use `Out-File -Enc Ascii` to write back out to the file in ASCII:

```
$contents | Out-File foo.txt -Enc Ascii
```